# Pushed large files without using git lfs

Tags: git, github

I just found out due to the warning when I pushed in the github repo, that for large binary files, we should use git lfs. I didn't know about it and hadn't installed it.

I haven't merged the push into the dev branch, yet I'm worried if it'll cause any inconsistent state, since, most of my team members seem to already know this and use git lfs for VCS. What would happen? Does git automatically resolve this? Or, what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the full text of the warning? Its important to know if it was just a warning or if your push was actually rejected.

Comment: In any case if your team members use `git lfs`, its best to have consistency throughout a team, so you should install it (and potentially ask them for help to do so).

Comment: @SamBob , So sorry, I wish I knew that, the chat history is long gone, but, the push was not rejected, it was only a warning and my PR got created. Does that mean I won't have to do steps suggested by Antonio? i will henceforth remember to use git lfs, but, it'd to so good, it I could just not have to do it this time around.

Comment: @BumbleBee what did you do in your issue? I have got same warning and cannot figure out what I should do then.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to (before merging):

1. Remove you binary file [Git BFG repo cleaner tool](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (you follow the tutorial on the website, it is not so trivial).
2. Install **Git LFS**.
3. Commit again the binary file by **Git LFS**.

Comment: the push was not rejected, it was only a warning and my PR got created. Does that mean I won't have to do steps suggested by above? Also, a tonne of thanks for the steps